# dwarf: variable offset from base

Tags: binary-analysis, elf, symbols, debugging-symbols

I have a simple code:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 4;
  printf("%d\n", a);
  a = 8;
  if (a == 8)
    printf("%d\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

DIEs for the function and variable:

```
 <1><32a>: Abbrev Number: 18 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <32b>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <32b>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x19c): main
    <32f>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <330>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <331>   DW_AT_decl_column : 5
    <332>   DW_AT_type        : <0x63>
    <336>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x4004b2
    <33e>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x4b
    <346>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c        (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <348>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
 <2><348>: Abbrev Number: 19 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <349>   DW_AT_name        : a
    <34b>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <34c>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 6
    <34d>   DW_AT_decl_column : 7
    <34e>   DW_AT_type        : <0x63>
    <352>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 6c     (DW_OP_fbreg: -20)
```

And objdump output for the same:

```
00000000004004b2 <main>:
  4004b2:       55                      push   rbp
  4004b3:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4004b6:       48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
  4004ba:       c7 45 fc 04 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x4
  4004c1:       8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  4004c4:       89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
  4004c6:       bf 84 05 40 00          mov    edi,0x400584
  4004cb:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4004d0:       e8 db fe ff ff          call   4003b0 <printf@plt>
  4004d5:       c7 45 fc 08 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x8
  4004dc:       83 7d fc 08             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x8
  4004e0:       75 14                   jne    4004f6 <main+0x44>
  4004e2:       8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  4004e5:       89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
  4004e7:       bf 84 05 40 00          mov    edi,0x400584
  4004ec:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4004f1:       e8 ba fe ff ff          call   4003b0 <printf@plt>
  4004f6:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4004fb:       c9                      leave
  4004fc:       c3                      ret
  4004fd:       0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
```

I am curious if detecting variable offset from ebp (assuming ebp is stack base and variable is on stack) is possible, by looking at debugging symbols. For e.g. in this case variable `a` is present at `rbp-0x4`. It looks like tag `DW_AT_location` could give me the location information. But, as per the dwarf documentation - 0x91 belongs to `DW_OP_fbreg` and 0x6C belongs to `DW_AT_const_expr`. I don't really get the meaning of this. I also read that `DW_AT_frame_base` gives the frame base of the function.

I really appreciate any help.